# POST Ajax bad request

Tags: ajax

I am trying AJAX post request with no avail. I tried a lot of answers here in the matter already, including localizing admin-ajax scripts, adding action to the data field, providing headers, providing priv and no_priv hooks.

I am pretty sure, that it is some stupid little mistake, but it takes much longer than it should already. I appreciate your help.

My javascript:

```
var variation = { name: 'personal', id: '467' };
var options   = {
    url : WC_VARIATION_ADD_TO_CART.ajax_url,
    method: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json', // tried without it too
    dataType: 'json', // tried without it too
    data: {
        "action"        : "woocommerce_add_variation_to_cart",
        "product_id"    : "466",
        "quantity"      : 1,
        "variation_name": variation.name,
        "variation_id"  : variation.id,
    },
}

options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);

$.ajax(options).done(function(success) {

    console.log(success);

}).fail(function(err) {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

My `functions.php`

```
wp_register_script( 
    'fluent-js', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/fluent-kit.full.min.js', 
    array(), 
    null, 
    true
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'fluent-js');
$vars = array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'fluent-js', 'WC_VARIATION_ADD_TO_CART', $vars );

function woocommerce_add_variation_to_cart() {

    echo json_encode(array("msg" => "Good"));
    die();

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_add_variation_to_cart', 'woocommerce_add_variation_to_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_add_variation_to_cart', 'woocommerce_add_variation_to_cart' );
```

My DevTools / Network tab:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code and got it to work by removing the following line as it is unnessacary.

`options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);`

You can also safely remove the following lines in your AJAX call.

```
contentType: 'application/json', // tried without it too
dataType: 'json', // tried without it too
```

Please check out [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) on the WordPress Codex for more info.